# How to display the content of an XML file in a HTML input with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, xml

I am trying to make a simple web based jQuery xml editor.
So.. the simplest solution I found is to take it's entire content of the xml file and place it into an input.
After that I can edit it, and then save it (haven't thought about how can I do that yet, but if you have any ideas please help).

```
function displayXMLContent(obj) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: obj.children().attr('title'),
        success: function (data) {
            $('#inputToEditXML').html(data);
            accessForTextArea(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of $('#inputToEditXML').html(data);

do

$('#inputToEditXML').**text**(data);

Comment: Actually .val seems the solution to add something with jQuery to a input, but the actual data of the xml is not inputed, i just get "[object XMLDocument]". I understand why, but how do I acces what I actually want? Thank you.

Comment: Ahh, see if this fixes your problem:  

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?34553-Convert-DOM-XML-Document-to-string